Gang leader chooses petty revenge over live with his wife and kids
A 2005 - 2010 tv show.
I remember there were two guys, a bad guy and a good guy.
The bad guy was heavily involved in crime and helped the good guy in exchange for the name of a guy that ratted him out many years ago. That's all the bad guy wants, to get even with the man that got him locked up.
The good guy is constantly telling him to not go through with his plans.  Despite the good guy's pleas to not go through with his plan, he gives the bad guy the information he wants, the location of the rat.
The bad guy has a wife and kid to whom he says goodbye to. They want him to live with them but he doesn't want to. He arrives at what he thinks is the rat's place with his mafia mates, they have their guns out. however, it's revealed to be a police sting setup by the good guy. Floodlights come on catching them on the lawn of this dummy place.
Bad guy gets out of this sting pickle only to die in police crossfire at a motel.  He had an opportunity to surrender, but instead pulled out a gun to die by police shooting.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Sorry Paulie D, first time asking anything on this site

This might be a duplicate.  You probably want to explore the search and tags features.  The description definitely rings a bell, as a question for this site.

Not a lot to go on, but this could be the TV show Prison Break.
A mobster (John Abruzzi) agrees to help the protagonist (Michael Scofield) break his brother out of prison in exchange for the location of the man who ratted Abruzzi out (a man named Fibonacci.)
While in prison, Michael repeatedly promises to make good on his word to tell Abruzzi where Fibonacci is, to secure Abruzzi's continued support.
In season 2, the characters escape and go on the run.  Abruzzi is reunited with his wife and kids and plans to flee the country, but he receives a tip on Fibonacci's location and decides to go after his revenge instead.
The tip turns out to be a trap, and Abruzzi is killed in the resulting sting operation.
I don't think the tip actually came from Michael in the end, though (it's been a while since I watched the show.)  I'm pretty sure it was an FBI operation that trapped him.

Yes!! Thankyou so much! I had it right on the tip of my tongue, had a feeling it was a tv show, wanted to say breaking bad but I knew that wasn't right and I couldn't think of another. But yes it was prison break. Thankyou so much!

Still can't find the sequence though where in johns guys go to kill Fibonacci, but they are busted by the cops, meanwhile Fibonacci is safe at another location?

@Aaron The scene where Abruzzi gets killed in the sting operation happens in S02E04 - "First Down."  I don't know if it exactly matches what you remember, but there were also a lot of these sorts of "fake-out" scenes in the show, where we think one person is about to get caught but then it turns out to be someone else.

How do I mark as answered?
